# a fixed value for tkinter scale bar but the range still from 0-180

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to write a python GUI coding to control servo motor movement with tkinter Scale widget.
Below if my coding.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep
from pyfirmata import Arduino, SERVO
HomePageGeo = "900x400"
board = Arduino('COM3')
sleep(0)
pinS1 = 2
board.digital[pinS1].mode = SERVO
class App:
    def __init__(self, window, window_title):
        self.window = window
        self.window.title(window_title)
        self.HomePage(window)
        self.window.mainloop()
    def HomePage(self,window):
        self.window.geometry(HomePageGeo)
        self.ServoControl(window)
    def ServoControl(self, window):
        # Define Servo Motor #####################
        def servo1(positions1):
            board.digital[pinS1].write(positions1)
            print(positions1)
        ### --> Angle 1 position bar
        angle1 = Scale(window,command=servo1,troughcolor='gray', cursor='dot',
                       from_=0, to=180, orient=HORIZONTAL,label='Angle 1 Position',
                       length=300, width=30 )
        angle1.pack()
App(tkinter.Tk(), 'Servo Motor Control')
```

Is there any idea or suggestion that when i run the program, the scalebar value shown is (eg. 60), but the range of scalebar still from 0 to 180 ?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you just asking how to set the initial value to 60? Have you tried `angle1.set(60)`?

Comment: I just tried this and it is working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

To set the default value for the scale, call the `set` method after creating it:

```
angle1.set(60)
```